# How to achieve blake2AsHex functionality from Polkadot.js in Substrate?

Tags: rust, substrate

I want to use the `blake2AsHex` kind of function in Rust. This function [exists](https://polkadot.js.org/common/util-crypto/modules/_blake2_ashex_.html#blake2ashex) in javascript but I am looking for a corresponding function in rust. So far, using the primitives of Substrate which are:

```
pub fn blake2_256(data: &[u8]) -> [u8; 32]
// Do a Blake2 256-bit hash and return result.
```

I am getting a different value.

When I execute this in console:

```
util_crypto.blake2AsHex("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")
```

I get the desired value: `0x33e423980c9b37d048bd5fadbd4a2aeb95146922045405accc2f468d0ef96988`. However, when I execute this rust code:

```
let res = hex::encode(&blake2_256("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001".as_bytes()));
println!("File Hash encoding: {:?}", res);
```

I get a different value:

```
47016246ca22488cf19f5e2e274124494d272c69150c3db5f091c9306b6223fc
```

Hence, how can I implement `blake2AsHex` in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again you have an issue with data types here.

```
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001".as_bytes()
```

is converting a big string to bytes, not the hexadecimal representation.

You need to correctly create the bytearray that you want to represent, and then it should work.

You are already using `hex::encode` for bytes to hex string... you should be using `hex::decode` for hex string to bytes:

https://docs.rs/hex/0.3.1/hex/fn.decode.html

> Decodes a hex string into raw bytes.

Comment: Why would I convert hex to bytes?

I was unable to understand where am I using the wrong datatype. I have to convert my hash to bytes using `to_bytes()` as `blake2_256` needs it in that format. Are you suggesting not to use `blake2_256`?

If I have to use `blake2_256`, I will have to convert it to`hex` string to query it.

Comment: I am saying that "0x01".as_bytes() is taking the bytes of some string "0x01". It is not treating it as a bytes, which is what you need. All the hex strings you see are really byte arrays.

Comment: So how can I make it treat it as bytes?